# Exception with WCF Service after Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on a WCF Service with Visual Studio Comunity 2015.
After upgrade my machine to Windows 10, and trying to start my project i get this error:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Ok. I remove the reference and any the DLL from project subfolders. Try and nothing. I reference the DLL and nothing. One thing I notices is that if i reference the DLL from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv (version 10.0.10240) and open the .csproj file i see this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Wich is a diferent version from the one i have in my system.

**EDIT II**
So I try to remove all the references to Microsoft.web.Administration, clean the solution and then add the reference to the file in  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.
After that clean again and recompile. When I open the .csproj file I see this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The version is different from the one in my system. What do I do now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ServerManager constructor crashes in test environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405595/servermanager-constructor-crashes-in-test-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when MSVS is trying to start the wrong version of Microsoft.Web.administration.

You can check for your current version here:

`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll`

You can edit your project file (e.g. in notepad) to correct the discrepancy.

Relevant links:

- [ServerManager constructor crashes in test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405595/servermanager-constructor-crashes-in-test-environment)
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1944833.aspx?Trying+to+get+Microsoft+Web+Administration+working

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i can't figure out what do i need to change. The file you mention (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll) is version 10.0.10240. I don't have a reference in my host project to that library.

Comment: I try to reference this file in my project and get the same error

Comment: OK: that's definitely the problem.  You got a new Microsoft.Web.Administration .dll when you upgraded ... and MSVS doesn't know about it.  Just do a global search in your project subfolders.  Alternatively, you might consider browsing to the new, current .dll in MSVS > Project > Add References.

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what I was trying to say.  Change "7.9.0.0" to "10.0.10240" in your .csproj!  Does it work?  PS: ".csproj" is what I meant by your "Project file".

Comment: No, same problem. Also try add the reference with nuget, but same problem

Comment: Do this: 1) MSVS > Solution  References > Add reference > Browse, add your current C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll. 2) Save All, Clean and Rebuild your project, 3) Make sure the .csproj now says "Version=10.0.x.x".  *IT WILL ALSO HAVE A DIFFERENT PublicKeyToken* 4) Post back what you find, 5) Post back if you encounter any problems doing this

Comment: The problem is clear.  The solution *should* be simple - I'm not sure why it hasn't worked for you yet.  Please read this: [Don't use the MWA packages at NuGet](https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/05/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Solution wasn't simple at all. I have to re-install windows 10 from scratch and reinstall VS2015 and everything worked like it should. Thanks for your effort!